# Change color of scatter point w.r.t a feature

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas Dataframe that has 3 features(columns), namely X,Y and Z.
X and Y are lists that contain data, whereas Z contains a list of string values(colors -Red & Blue). I want a scatter plot with x-axis as feature X and y-axis with feature Y, with the scatter points colored according to the values in Z.

For ex. If the value in Z for a row is Red, color the point red, and blue if its Blue.

```
data_frame['X'] = pandas.Series(X)
data_frame['Y'] = pandas.Series(Y)
data_frame['Z'] = pandas.Series(Z)

data_frame.plot(kind='scatter', x='X', y='Y')
pl.show()
```

The plot is working fine, but I can't figure out how to implement the color part. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)      # pandas series works too
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
circle = 100* np.ones(50)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors, s=circle, alpha=0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image: the resulting plot]

Answer (score 2):

You could try using seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lmplot("X", "Y", data= data_frame, hue='Z', fit_reg=False)
```

Comment: It does work fine, but can you tell me how to it with either matplotlib or pandas? I want to use as less modules as possible.